# How can I pass username and password in React Native Linking?

Tags: javascript, react-native, url

I have imported Linking from React Native in my app for opening urls. But the url which I am using requires username and password, and after using Linking it every-times ask for username and password in my app. Is there any way in which I can pass username and password inside my Linking code?

```
Linking.openURL(url).catch((err) => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url need to include query params, for example:

`https://www.google.com/search?q=react+native`